# "nativecode=1060 ** Duplicate column name 'created_id'" when upgrading from 4.4.14 to 4.6.2

Tags: upgrade, civicrm-home

Keep getting this error when Upgrading from 4.4.14 to 4.6.2 directly. I am upgrading based on the civicrm documentation.

Seems like civicm_mailing_abtest has some error. But I have checked I did not have this table in 4.4 version and it was created during the upgrade process.

How to deal with it?

[image]

DB Error: unknown error in unknown on line unknown
nativecode=1060 ** Duplicate column name 'created_id'
ALTER TABLE civicrm_mailing_abtest ADD COLUMN `created_id` int unsigned

Comment: Did you somehow try to run the upgrade multiple times? Do you have a backup of the original database?

Comment: Yes, I have backup of original civi db. I tried to installed on multiple instances from backup plus on a brand new install. It always fails! Upgrading from 4.4.14!!

Comment: Tapash - can you confirm whether you used a MySQL 'DROP DATABASE cividatabasename' and 'CREATE DATABASE cividatabasename' between installs?

Comment: I tried upgrade by the civicrm book, nothing otherwise.

Comment: just got exact same on site upgrading from 4.4.19. Same spot 4.6.alpha7 - i didn't set this running so not sure if sql backup had any special treatment. tapash do you recall anything more about getting past this? it is odd since we had done a test upgrade for them many many months ago and i don't see any record of hitting this that time

Comment: ok. so yep seems to be the case that DROP database didn't happen and yes this was a db that had an upgrade on it over 9 months ago.

Answer (score 2):

That looks very strange error, it appears to be complaining that the created_id column is being created twice, However looking through the upgrade sql files on the github repo, I can only see the one reference to creating created_id column on that table and that is in the 4.6alpha7.sql file. I do note that it came from this JIRA case https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15970. Perhaps you should raise it as a bug in the Jira system but also would recommend looking through the upgrade sql files on your system to see if they match what is in the git repo